# Strapi with MongoDB (macOS): error while creating the project with the command "npx create-strapi-app my-project"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, strapi

I am trying to create a Strapi application with MongoDB and I am following the docs on the website, but when configuring the connection, I get this error and I am not understanding why.

[Error I get everytime (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ1zM.png)
[Log's error (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKmqo.png)

Error:

"Connection test failed: Command failed: npm install --prefix /var/folders/gb/519s_wwn1ps0c0skqw7_03140000gn/T/strapi40136a8b0f29 strapi-connector-mongoose@3.5.4
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'spec' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/red/.npm/_logs/2021-04-08T09_37_12_689Z-debug.log"

MongoDB was installed using Brew and is running as a service.
Node version is 14.16.1.
NPM version is 7.8.0.
Never had a problem like this before with any sort of package or similar.
I already tried to: uninstall MongoDB and reinstall it, reinstall Node and npm.

When I run `npm install -g npm-reinstall` I get this instead and I think it is related to the problem:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umr6B.jpg)

What I need to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the registry of npm config.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade npm to its previous version to avoid this error.

`npm install -g npm@6`